# CiviDiscount of 100% create zero amount payment

Tags: cividiscount

I have a set up where events carry a fee, but using CiviDiscount a 100% discount is offered to logged in members. This basically works fine, BUT it still creates a payment/contribution for each member registration, with a paid sum of zero.

Is there a way of preventing the creation of a zero contribution altogether?

Comment: What version are you using?  This sounds like a problem that I thought was fixed some time ago.

Comment: Thanks @Aidan, I was in fact using 3.7, not having noticed the new versions in January. But after upgrading to 3.8.1, the problem persists (have cleared cache, etc). Have tried this twice, with and without prices set. Have I configured something wrongly?

Comment: Ah, maybe I misunderstood this originally!  I was thinking of the situation where it tried to process a zero payment.  But this is different: it does not try to process a zero payment via the processor but it does record a zero contribution.  That's probably by design so that you can distinguish between using the discount and no payment being recorded.  Is the zero contribution causing a problem?

Comment: Ah yes, I hadn't thought of that. I guess it isn't cause much of a problem apart from a long list of zero payments in the list. Thanks for helping me see the logic here.